# How do I get the 'count' in scrollWheel event?

Tags: swift, macos, nsscrollview

When overriding scrollWheel() method, I can see in the event.description a 'count:' that is incremented when I scroll continuously on a trackpad.

```
override func scrollWheel( with event: NSEvent )
{
    print( event )
}
```

The output while scrolling:

```
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8103.7 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-1.000000 deltaY=0.000000 count:0 phase=Began momentumPhase=None
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8103.7 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-8.000000 deltaY=1.000000 count:0 phase=Changed momentumPhase=None
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8103.7 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-13.000000 deltaY=1.000000 count:0 phase=Changed momentumPhase=None
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8103.7 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-18.000000 deltaY=2.000000 count:0 phase=Changed momentumPhase=None
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8103.7 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-24.000000 deltaY=2.000000 count:0 phase=Changed momentumPhase=None
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8103.7 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-92.000000 deltaY=5.000000 count:1 phase=Changed momentumPhase=None
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8103.8 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-47.000000 deltaY=2.000000 count:1 phase=Changed momentumPhase=None
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8103.8 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-54.000000 deltaY=3.000000 count:1 phase=Changed momentumPhase=None
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8103.8 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-84.000000 deltaY=0.000000 count:1 phase=None momentumPhase=Began
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8103.8 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-240.000000 deltaY=0.000000 count:1 phase=None momentumPhase=Changed
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8103.9 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-73.000000 deltaY=0.000000 count:1 phase=None momentumPhase=Changed
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8103.9 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-69.000000 deltaY=0.000000 count:1 phase=None momentumPhase=Changed
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8103.9 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-65.000000 deltaY=0.000000 count:1 phase=None momentumPhase=Changed
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8103.9 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-62.000000 deltaY=0.000000 count:1 phase=None momentumPhase=Changed
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8103.9 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-58.000000 deltaY=0.000000 count:1 phase=None momentumPhase=Changed
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8103.9 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-54.000000 deltaY=0.000000 count:1 phase=None momentumPhase=Changed
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8104.0 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-51.000000 deltaY=0.000000 count:1 phase=None momentumPhase=Changed
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8104.0 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-47.000000 deltaY=0.000000 count:1 phase=None momentumPhase=Changed
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8104.0 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-43.000000 deltaY=0.000000 count:1 phase=None momentumPhase=Changed
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8104.0 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-39.000000 deltaY=0.000000 count:1 phase=None momentumPhase=Changed
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8104.0 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=0.000000 deltaY=0.000000 count:1 phase=None momentumPhase=Ended
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8104.0 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-11.000000 deltaY=0.000000 count:2 phase=Began momentumPhase=None
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8104.0 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-56.000000 deltaY=2.000000 count:2 phase=Changed momentumPhase=None
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8104.1 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-61.000000 deltaY=3.000000 count:2 phase=Changed momentumPhase=None
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8104.1 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-82.000000 deltaY=4.000000 count:2 phase=Changed momentumPhase=None
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8104.1 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-106.000000 deltaY=6.000000 count:2 phase=Changed momentumPhase=None
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8104.1 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-110.000000 deltaY=7.000000 count:2 phase=Changed momentumPhase=None
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8104.1 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-68.000000 deltaY=5.000000 count:2 phase=Changed momentumPhase=None
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(1036.14,554.34) time=8104.1 flags=0 win=0x10dd080c0 winNum=890 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-152.000000 deltaY=0.000000 count:2 phase=None momentumPhase=Began
```

How can I actually get the "Count" from the NSEvent as there is no such variable or method?

Comment: Could be the `clickCount` property of the event?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Koen, but `clickCount` is not available in ScrollWheel NSEvents.

Comment: Why do you want the count value?  Don't you just want the x/y delta values?

Comment: @trojanfoe Because I want to limit the scroll to the first gesture. If the user scroll a second time while the initial scroll isn't finished it should be ignored.

Comment: Not really because I the previous phase did not ended (or the momentumPhase), so I have no information if it is the same gesture or another. And as the information is in description and debugDescription I presume it is available somewhere.

Comment: Try the Swift version of `CGEventGetIntegerValueField(event.CGEvent, kCGScrollWheelEventScrollCount)`.

Comment: Just curious, what does the value mean? The docs for `kCGScrollWheelEventScrollCount` are not very helpful.

Comment: @koen, the count increases when the user make another scroll gesture while the scroll phase (or momentumPhase) did not end. It does not correspond to the number of gesture but it increases as fast the user scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Willeke, here is the Swift version:

```
override func scrollWheel( with event: NSEvent )
{
    print( event )
    if let count = event.cgEvent?.getIntegerValueField( CGEventField.scrollWheelEventScrollCount )
    {
        print( count )
    }
}
```

```
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(824.82,567.461) time=12769.8 flags=0 win=0x10db2fa10 winNum=1327 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=0.000000 deltaY=0.000000 count:0 phase=MayBegin momentumPhase=None
0
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(824.82,567.461) time=12769.8 flags=0 win=0x10db2fa10 winNum=1327 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-5.000000 deltaY=0.000000 count:0 phase=Began momentumPhase=None
0
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(824.82,567.461) time=12769.8 flags=0 win=0x10db2fa10 winNum=1327 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-18.000000 deltaY=1.000000 count:0 phase=Changed momentumPhase=None
0
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(824.82,567.461) time=12769.9 flags=0 win=0x10db2fa10 winNum=1327 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-35.000000 deltaY=2.000000 count:1 phase=Changed momentumPhase=None
1
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(824.82,567.461) time=12769.9 flags=0 win=0x10db2fa10 winNum=1327 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-84.000000 deltaY=4.000000 count:1 phase=Changed momentumPhase=None
1
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(824.82,567.461) time=12769.9 flags=0 win=0x10db2fa10 winNum=1327 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-92.000000 deltaY=6.000000 count:1 phase=Changed momentumPhase=None
1
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(824.82,567.461) time=12769.9 flags=0 win=0x10db2fa10 winNum=1327 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-103.000000 deltaY=9.000000 count:1 phase=Changed momentumPhase=None
1
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(824.82,567.461) time=12770.1 flags=0 win=0x10db2fa10 winNum=1327 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=0.000000 deltaY=0.000000 count:1 phase=None momentumPhase=Ended
1
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(824.82,567.461) time=12770.1 flags=0 win=0x10db2fa10 winNum=1327 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-25.000000 deltaY=0.000000 count:2 phase=Began momentumPhase=None
2
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(824.82,567.461) time=12770.1 flags=0 win=0x10db2fa10 winNum=1327 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-84.000000 deltaY=2.000000 count:2 phase=Changed momentumPhase=None
2
NSEvent: type=ScrollWheel loc=(824.82,567.461) time=12770.1 flags=0 win=0x10db2fa10 winNum=1327 ctxt=0x0 deltaX=-89.000000 deltaY=3.000000 count:2 phase=Changed momentumPhase=None
```